# Unable to capture browser console logs when using SeleniumWebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser

I am trying to capture all the console errors that will happen in the browser while running my tests. I am using Selenium Webdriver to simulate the browser.

```
console.log = console.log.bind(console);
console.logs = [];
console.log = function() {
console.logs.push(Array.from(arguments));
console.log.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

However, I am not able to capture logs in "logs" when I run the browser related tests.

When I use pure javascript to test my code I see I am able to get some output but in this case "logs" array remains empty.

Any ideas on whether the binding with Console is not happening properly or whether something else is wrong with my implementation here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide your webdriver code? This doesn't appear to be a [mcve], so I'm not sure what the problem and expected output are.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
var con = console.log.bind(console);
con("pepe");
```

Its the equivalent of doing:

```
console.log("pepe");
```

What you wish to do, I think can be done as:

```js
var originalLog = console.log;

var logs = [];
console.log = function() {
  logs.push(arguments);
  originalLog.apply(this, arguments);
};

console.log("a");
console.log("b");
console.log("c");

// Lets print what logs is holding
$( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery.each(logs, function(){
    var elem = $(this)[0];
    
    $("#divLog").append($('<div>' + elem + '</div>'));
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divLog"></div>
```